# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE) in /home/u663911524/public_html/sitemap.php on line 3

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE) in /home/u663911524/public_html/sitemap.php on line 3

I have searched online for solutions for a while and none seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm still new to php as well.

Here are the first couple of lines of code:

```
<? php     
require("sitemap.cfg");
$isoLastModifiedSite = "";
$newLine = "\n";
$indent = " ";
if (!$rootUrl) exit;
```

Comment: Remove the space between `<` and `php`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Change

```
<? php
```

to

```
<?php
```

And the error will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There is an space between `<?` and `php`

Erase it